# How to print numbers from 1 to 1000 and then only even numbers within the same loop

Tags: python, for-loop, numbers, range

I have the task of printing the numbers from 1 to 1000 with only using two lines of code. Which I've managed to do. The problem I'm having is **within the same loop** I have to print a separate list of numbers using the modular operator "%2". My current code below is printing the numbers from 1 to 1000 but then in between its printing if the number is devisible by 2 and printing true or false. I need to print this new list of even numbers separately.

my code is as follows:

```
for num in range(1,1001):
    print (num)
    num2 = num%2==0
    print (num2)
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Add an if statement

Comment: Can you show what the result is supposed to look like (just use 1 to 10)?

Comment: The modulo operator should be used in an `if` test to check if a number is even, you shouldn't print the result of the test.

Comment: If the even numbers are supposed to be printed separately, I don't think it can be done in the same loop. It will always mix the two lists together.

Comment: I am able to print the lists separately if I use another loop but Im not sure its possible to do it within the same loop?

Comment: also changing it to an if statement does print the even numbers but in between the initial list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unpacking with range like this:

```
for i in (1,2):
    print(*range(i,1001,i))
```

And if you want to print each number in new line, just change a few things like:

```
for i in (1,2):
    print(*range(i,1001,i), sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really ugly code. But this works.

```
for i in range(1, 1001):
    print("{}{}".format(i, "" if i % 2 else "\n{}".format(i // 2)))
```

Comment: why the division?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be easier (one loop, two lines of code):

```
for i in range(1) :
    print range(1,1001), '\n', range(2,1001,2)
```

will output for numbers (1~10):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

If you are using python3, you need to add parentheses to `print( ... )` call, also wrap `range()` in `list()`, like `list(range(...))`. But that's just minor changes.

Comment: what's the purpose of the loop here?

Comment: @Tomerikoo OP said (s)he needed a loop. don't know why, but here it is.